# Openstreetmaps with custom data in directions

Tags: openstreetmap, directions

Is there any way to create a route with custom data with openstreetmaps ? I tried the mapbox but the directions there looks like they can't do that.

Comment: Please explain "custom data". Do you want to modify / add new data to existing OSM data?

Comment: I want to add some variables on each road to run my shortest path algorithm and get my path.